# Crystal Report simple counter 1 to 15

Tags: loops, for-loop, crystal-reports

I am currently new to Crystal Reporting and I have no idea how to do a looping statement.
Is it possible to create a counter using for loop then print the numbers from 1 to 15?

P.S. No data field will be used

For example (this is in java but I want it to be in Crystal Report)

```
int count;

for(count = 1; count <= 15;count++)

System.out.print( count+",");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should return the wanted result:

```
NumberVar i;
StringVar str;

For i := 1 To 15 Do
(
   str := str & CStr(i,0,"") & ","
);

str
```

The part `CStr(i,0,"")` converts the number to a string and removes decimals and the thousands separator.

Comment: Is it possible for each output to be printed as a data field? For example, output is a new row, 2 is another row and so on.

Comment: You can change the comma to `chr(10)` to add a new line instead of a comma, but you can't make it a data field. There may be another approach to reach your goal, but for me it's not clear what you want? Maybe this is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...?

Comment: I am currently making a employee time-in/time-out system. I am planning to imitate a dtr card. I was able to display the employee name and his time-in/time-out. Only missing part was the dates so I was planning on doing a loop then display all of the 15 numbers as a row in line with the employee data

Comment: I guess then it would be better to create a new question with appropriate details so one can help you.